# Is installing multiple OS in External Hard Drive harmful?

Tags: external-hard-drive, multi-boot

I have installed Ubuntu,Lubuntu and Linux Mint in my 2TB External Hard Drive. All are working fine, but seems like external is heating up very fast(also may not be cause I didn't see how much it is heating before installing multiple OSes).

So is installing multiple OSes in External Hard Disk harmful for HDD? I'm talking about only the hardware problem may arise or data corruption.

Comment: Not anymore harmful than installing multiple OSes on an internal HDD. I assume you are using an eSATA or USB 3.0 connection? Download some temperature monitoring software, such as HWMonitor, and see how it compares to an internal HDD. If it's way hotter, like 10-20 Celsius, than there is an issue. Also check to see the maximum temperature the drive should be operating at.

Comment: Of course it's not harmful, the drive doesn't know or care what or how many OSs are on there.  Even filling it will files to the brim shouldn't affect the heat dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on the plastic housing surrounding the external hard disk. If there's sufficient ventilation then you shouldn't experience a shortened life, though manufacturers do make housing pretty compact because external hard drives aren't intended to run for a constant period of time like an internal OS hard disk would.